# During deploying contract in go ethereum how other contract gets to know where other one is when they are inherited?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-design, contract-development

when we deploy two contracts in go ethereum and one is inherited by the other ,when we deploy contracts differently how other contracts gets to know where the other contract is and it is able to access the functions of the parent contract ?

Comment: i was working with the inheritance and i was able to try multiple,multi level inheritance by calling function from parent contracts from child.I am confused how one contract is getting to know where the other contract is in geth ,as m deploying them separately.

Comment: i used online compiler for the purpose and copied the compiled code from left panel from web deploy box and deployed.I want to know how internally it is getting to know about the parent and child contracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once published on the chain, child and parent contract are merged into the child contract. So when you access parent functions on a child contract, you actually access a function that is in the child contract.
Inheritance is only existing to make development easier and code more readable, but once you are on the chain everything is concatenated in one.

Comment: thanks man  merging is done at compile time only ?

Comment: I don't really know in detail how solc does that but yes, it's compile time as the transaction have to carry the full code of the contracts and no further code manipulation is done once the creation transaction is sent to the chain.